# Thinking Sphinx deployment problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx

In deploying a rails 3.2.18 application with thinking_sphinx, I am getting two new unobserved (in previously installed applications of same server) behaviours.

```
bundle exec rake ts:config
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'ts:config'
```

and

```
bundle exec rake ts:index
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: (erb):7: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
/Users/me/fna/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:135:in `settings_to_hash'
/Users/me/fna/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:100:in `settings'
/Users/me/fna/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:145:in `setup'
/Users/me/fna/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:13:in `initialize'
/Users/me/fna/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:17:in `new'
/Users/me/fna/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:17:in `instance'
/Users/me/fna/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:68:in `configuration'
/Users/me/fna/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:12:in `configure'
/Users/me/fna/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:24:in `index'
/Users/me/fna/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Have I missed something in the overall set-up?

Answer (score 1):

The task is `ts:configure` (`ts:config` may have existed with pre TS v3 releases, but certainly does not now).

Comment: I stand corrected.  However, am still getting the same `invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)` error with `ts:configure`...

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that the first time around. What version of Ruby are you using in development? And is there anything in `config/thinking_sphinx.yml` that's not valid UTF-8?

Comment: Figured out the hang up.  Had created the files as copies of localhost ones... but forgot to look at what the text editor was saving as default encoding.  Needed to sit in the barber's chair to come up with that one!  Cheers!